# How can we count different coloring in 2 cycle with one edge in common

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

There is a question that asked *what is the counts of different coloring in $C_5$ and $C_6$ when it has one edge in common*:
[image: c5 and c6 with one edge in common]
I have used fundamental reduction in cycles in order to get a recursive formula (I know there is a closed formula for that too), but when i try use the same in this particular question, it becomes very complicated. How can I find a formula for this kind of graph? Im looking for Chromatic Polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first find a formula for a "mouse graph" ($C_n$ with a path $P_m$ attached)

[image: mouse-6,3 graph]

This is easy with induction and the fundamental d-c. We know that for $n$-cycle the chromatic polynomial is $C_n(x) = (x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1)$ and we get that for the mouse it is

$$M_{n,m}(x) = (x-1)^m C_n(x)$$

Now for the graph in question. Let's denote the chromatic polynomial by $P_{n,m}$, where $n$ is the number of nodes in the first cycle and $m$ is the extra nodes in the second. So what we want is $P_{6, 3}$.

When we use deletion-contraction on the first edge that comes out on the second cycle, we get the recursion (and the basecase $P_{n,0} (x) = C_n(x)$)

$$P_{n,m}(x) = M_{n,m}(x) - P_{n,m-1}(x)\\
= M_{n,m}(x) - M_{n,m-1}(x) + P_{n,m-2}(x)\\
= \dots =\\
= \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j M_{n,m-j}(x) = C_{n}(x)\sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j (x-1)^{m-j}\\
=  C_{n}(x)(-1)^m\sum_{j=0}^m  (1-x)^{j} \\
= C_n(x)(-1)^m\frac{1-(1-x)^{m+1}}{x}\\
= C_n(x)\frac{(x-1)^{m+1} + (-1)^m}{x}$$

You can check the answer with the following [SAGE](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)-code:

```
R.<x> = QQ['x']

def c(n):
    return x if n==1 else (x-1)**n + (-1)**n*(x-1)

def makeGraph(n, m):
    N = n+m
    g = Graph(N)
    for i in range(N): g.add_edge(i, (i+1)%N)
    if n>1 and m>1: g.add_edge(0, n-1)
    return g

def getFormula(n, m):
    #TODO doesn't work for n==1 or m==1
    p = c(n)*(-1)**m*(1-(1-x)**(m+1))/x
    return p


for n in range(1, 10):
    for m in range(1, 10):
        p = makeGraph(n,m).chromatic_polynomial()
        pFormula = getFormula(n,m)
        if p != pFormula:
            print("Wrong formula with %d, %d" %(n,m))
            print (p)
            print (pFormula)
```

**EDIT** The formula doesn't work for the cases where $n=1$ or $m=1$.

Comment: Your solution is correct. But i am wondering that  when we use d-c in common edge in contracting we have a C5 and C4 with one Vertex in common. Is there any simpler solution when we have one vertex in common instead of one edge in common

Comment: I really like your solution ! 

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) gives the chromatic polynomial of the cycle graph $C_n$ as $(x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1)$.  In your graph we can choose the first point that is common to the cycles in $x$ ways and the other point in common in $x-1$ ways.  That choice is common to the two cycles, then we can complete each in any way we want, so the chromatic polynomial is 
$$\frac {\left((x-1)^6+(-1)^6(x-1)\right)\left((x-1)^5+(-1)^5(x-1)\right)}{x(x-1)}=\\x^9 - 10 x^8 + 45 x^7 - 120 x^6 + 209 x^5 - 245 x^4 + 190 x^3 - 90 x^2 + 20 x=\\(x - 2) (x - 1) x (x^2 - 2 x + 2) (x^4 - 5 x^3 + 10 x^2 - 10 x + 5)$$
where I got [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-1%29%5E6%2Bx-1%29%28%28x-1%29%5E5-x%2B1%29%2Fx%2F%28x-1%29) to do the simplification.  The presence of $(x-1)(x-2)$ and no $(x-3)$ says the chromatic number is $3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is correct , did you use overcounting method first then undoing it with division ? I didn’t know we can use it in this kind of problems.

Comment: You could call it overcounting.  I thought of it as coloring the six cycle, which colors two vertices of the five cycle.  The division took out the options that have already been specified for the five cycle.

Comment: It is very interesting. Please correct me if i am wrong, you say when we have a cycle with k colored vertices we can assume it as a uncolored cycle then we consider colored vertices with x(x-1)(x-2)....(x-k+1) and undoing it with division ?

Comment: I did not derive the chromatic polynomial of a cycle, I just used it.  It comes from going around the cycle, where you generally have $x-1$ choices at each point after the first.  The $(-1)^n(x-1)$ term accounts for what happens at the end of an odd or even cycle.  I haven't looked through the details.  Your approach is incorrect because you can reuse colors and always have at least $x-2$ choices, so there should not be any terms in the product smaller than that.

Comment: This approach generalizes to a [$k$-clique sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Properties).